# Facebook integration with javascript FB Graph api Post on wall Unknown error in firefox

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, facebook-graph-api, jakarta-ee

I am posting on the user`s wall using the **FB Graph api** my function to post on wall is as follow:

```
 function PostToWall()
 {

      var mymessage = 'my message';
      var mypic = 'http://myapp/a.jpg';
      var mylink = 'http://www.myapp.com';
      var myname = 'myApp';
      var mydesc = 'my desc .';
      FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: mymessage, picture: mypic, link: mylink, name: myname, description: mydesc }, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                       alert(response.error.message);
            } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
             }
      });
      // alert('Do you want to continue ? ');
 };
```

it works fine in crome but when i use the same in firefox it prompts **Unknown error** from `alert(response.error.message);` .and in the error console of firefox error is

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 468"  data: no]
```

I found the solution is the prompt user before the end of the function see the last line **alert('Do you want to continue ? ');** . When i write this alert it works fine in firefox also but i do not want to promt user for any message. what could be the problem and what would be the solution ?

I am using firefox 5.0 . and my operating system is windows 7.

PostOnWall function is called from another function which is as follow:

```
function f(){

     PostToWall();
    ...
    ...
    //code to click a submit button
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to break on the callback with Firebug and see where the exception is thrown? I guess problem is that you do something immediately after calling PostToWall (such as redirecting browser etc..) that triggers the bug

Comment: may be because i am posting on user`s wall when he logs in my website. and i have to do that so what can be the solution ? It works fine with google crome..

Comment: Easy, just move the code after PostToWall to the FB.api callback handler.

Comment: can you give me an example how can i provide callback handler with FB.api ?

Comment: It works fine in crome just problem in firefox will it problem of redirection ?

Comment: see the edit which describers the page submit after the post on wall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written code to click a submit button in a callback handler as follow:

```
function PostToWallCallBackHandler(response) {
     if (!response || response.error) {
         alert(response.error.message);
     } else {
          document.getElementById('fbSubmit').click();
     }
 }
 function PostToWall(mymessage,mypic,mylink,myname,mydesc,callbackHandler) {
     FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: mymessage, picture: mypic, link: mylink, name: myname, description: mydesc },function (response){callbackHandler(response);} );
 };
```

it works fine with both crome and firefox,safari and IE 9.